# What was the shuffle called in Rocky III?

Tags: boxing

In rocky III, the training montage showed Apollo teaching Rocky a shuffle. at 0:23 and 1:00 it shows rocky learning a new footing and I was wondering if there was a name for it.

Comment: Did you mean to link to some kind of video? There aren't any links in your post right now.

Comment: It's called "Ali shuffle". Muhammad Ali popularized this footwork technique which involves a rapid shuffle of the feet in a quick, rhythmic pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a video attached but if my memory serves me correctly and it is what I think it is he was doing the "Ali shuffle"

Answer (score 0):

This is a scene from the training session of Rocky:

This is a demonstration by Muhammad Ali showing his foot work:

There are similar moves on both videos, but I'd rather call that a tribute rather than a copy.